# Using Semantic JS dropdown in Angular App

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I am working on improving the UI of a website, and needed to use Semantic JS with it. The website was written in Angular, and the one piece of Semantic functionality that was not working was Dropdowns. The styling worked fine, but as soon as I tried to initialize the dropdown with a

```
$('...').dropdown({options});
```

I encountered a "$('...').dropdown is not a function" error. Looked around and nowhere mentioned the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since SemanticJS modifies the $ operator from Jquery, Jquery needs to be included before SemanticJS.

```
//Index.html//
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="jquery.blah.min.js"></script>
    <script src="semantic.min.js"></script>
</html>
```